Problema en app React Native con AWS Cognito - CognitoIdentityProvider - initiateAuth
estoy teniendo problemas con la función initiateAuth de cognito.
Este es el archivo de la función:
import {
    AuthFlowType,
    CognitoIdentityProvider,
    InitiateAuthCommandInput,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider';
import Config from 'react-native-config';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import { getUserPool } from 'utils';

const provider = new CognitoIdentityProvider({
    region: Config.Region
});

//Sign
export const signIn = async (
    empresa: string,
    username: string,
    password: string
) => {
    let pool = await getUserPool(empresa);
    const command: InitiateAuthCommandInput = {
        AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
        ClientId: pool.ClientId,
        AuthParameters: {
            USERNAME: username,
            PASSWORD: password
        }
    };

    return await provider.initiateAuth(command);
};


Al ejecutarse la función me aparece el error:
Property 'ReadableStream' doesn't exist

Estuve investigando y la mayoria concuerda con la respuesta de:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77744609/15578292
Pero en mi caso al realizar eso me aparece el error:
null is not a function 

Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando ??
